# Mac Python IDLE import tensorflow error (but tensorflow works fine in command line)

Tags: macos, python-2.7, python-3.x, tensorflow, python-idle

I have a Macbook laptop running MacOS Sierra 10.12.

So I followed "Pip Installation" instructions here: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/os_setup.html#test-the-tensorflow-installation

And when I test the installation using a demo model suggested by using "python" in the command line as per here: 
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/os_setup.html#test-the-tensorflow-installation, 
it all seems to work as my machine goes ahead and trains a model.

But when I open up IDLE for Python 2.7 and type "import tensorflow as tf", I get a traceback error "ImportError: No module named tensorflow"

And when I open up IDLE for Python 3.5 and type "import tensorflow as tf", I get a very long error that ends with:

**ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so
  Reason: image not found**

So in my layman's understanding, I've somehow installed Tensorflow and I can access it via the command line in Terminal. But both of my IDLEs for different versions of Python are having difficulty with it.

I want to be able to write and run Python scripts for Tensorflow in IDLE (either Python 2.7 or 3.4) but I'm not sure how to get around these errors.

PS I'm also very new to the command line. All my life, installing something simply means clicking on some icon or dragging an icon into something else with my mouse. It's been a rough few days teaching myself how to do this.

Thank you greatly for any help you can provide.

Comment: According to the error messages, you have tensorflow installed for 3.5 but not 2.7, so ignore 2.7.  I believe that this is a non-standard error message specific either to Mac or tensorflow.  Import differences between console and IDLE can result from sys.path differences, but I don't believe this is the issue here, as python running IDLE seems to have found tensorflow.  Still, you might check the difference in `import sys; print(sys.path)`.  Are you running python3.5 downloaded from python.org?  How are you starting IDLE.  Also see question in answer box.

Comment: you say "...open up IDLE for Python **3.5** and..." but later you say "in IDLE (either Python 2.7 or **3.4**) "  I assume either `3.5` or `3.4` is a typo but do verify which version of python you are running and [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40324983/edit) accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install PyCharm (IDE), import tensorflow directly from their plugin.

To install a package

1. In the Project Interpreter page of the project settings, select the
   desired Python interpreter or virtual environment.
2. Click .
3. In the Available Packages dialog box that opens, select the desired
   package from the list. ...
4. If required, select the following check boxes:
5. ... Click Install Package.

Comment: I appreciate the pycharm suggestion. It appears to be a much more powerful environment and I can install all kinds of other modules as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

(This is a request and question, not an answer, but I need code formatting to ask it.)  Except for some intended or unavoidable (and known) differences, it is rare for python to execute code differently when it reads the code normally and when IDLE asks it to execute it.  Hence your report puzzles me.  Please cut and paste the following into a file, such as `testtf.py`.  Then run the file with python in your console.  (`python3 <path to>/testtf.py`)

```
import sys

try:
    import tensorflow
    print(tensorflow)
    del tensorflow, sys.modules['tensorflow']
except ImportError as e:
    print(e)

try:
    exec('import tensorflow', globals())
    print(tensorflow)
    del tensorflow, sys.modules['tensorflow']
except ImportError as e:
    print(e)

try:
    exec(compile('import tensorflow', 'shell', 'exec'), globals())
    print(tensorflow)
    del tensorflow, sys.modules['tensorflow']
except ImportError as e:
    print(e)
```

Each chunk should print something like `<module 'tensorflow' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py'>`.  What do you actually get?

This code tries 3 equivalent ways to import a module.  The first is what one normally enters and what you say works (in a console).  The second or third is what python does internally, and the third is how IDLE submits user code to python.  They should be equivalent, but seem not to be, so lets remove IDLE as a factor.

Comment: This is what I got:

<module 'tensorflow' from '/Users/ct_sphon/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.pyc'>
<module 'tensorflow' from '/Users/ct_sphon/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.pyc'>
<module 'tensorflow' from '/Users/ct_sphon/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.pyc'>

So I guess I'm good to go!! Thank you!!!